# Complex custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have **four** `Buttons` in The `MainActivity`, and I want to transfer the user to the 2nd `Activity` which is a `ListView`, but I want to code every `Button` to transfer different elements to that `ListView`. The question is That to code this `ListView` should I use Custom `ListView` Adapter or what  ????

Comment: where is your code

Comment: yes use custom list view adapter

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: I am looking for an answer to code that list view , and I am still confused because I couldn't code the list view with the arrays because every button has 2 arrays which means I have in list.java class about 8 arrays , So how can I specify every button to its arrays. I tired to loops in list.java class but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have one text view and two buttons in your list item then your custom adapter will look like this.
On firstButton Click open the first activity and on second activity open the second activity.

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel>  {

        private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
        Context mContext;

        // View lookup cache
        private static class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtName;
            Button   firstButton,secondButton;

        }

        public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data, Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
            this.dataSet = data;
            this.mContext=context;

        }


        private int lastPosition = -1;

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Get the data item for this position
            DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);
            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

            final View result;

            if (convertView == null) {

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
                viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                viewHolder.firstButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.first_button);
                viewHolder.secondButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.second_button);     
                result=convertView;

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                result=convertView;
            }


            lastPosition = position;

            viewHolder.txtName.setText(dataModel.getName());


            viewHolder.secondButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something when the corky is clicked
                open second activity
}
        });
            viewHolder.firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something when the corky is clicked
                open first activity
}
        });
            // Return the completed view to render on screen
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please note that the buttons are on the MainActivtiy ,not on the listview rows, So there's no meaning to code them in ViewHolder inner class

Answer (score 0):

this is the last listAdapter I'd coded but still has a bug in line 99 whis is    holder.mTitle.setText(titles[j][k]);

the whole code

```
    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data> {

    private int layoutResource ;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public ListAdapter(Activity act , int resource , ArrayList<Data> data){
        super(act ,resource,data);
        layoutResource = resource;
        activity = act;
        dataList = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Data getItem(int position) {
        return dataList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        int buttonPosition,titlePosition;
        View row= convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

       if ( row == null || (row.getTag()) ==null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
            row= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,viewGroup,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.mContent =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
```

int []buttonsName ={R.id.btnAchieveYourLifeGoals ,R.id.btnBecomeMoreOptimistic,R.id.btnBecomeWealthyAndSuccess,R.id.btnReduceStress,R.id.btnLeadership};enter code here

```
                   int [][]titles ={{R.string.createList1, R.string.cleanEnvironment1, R.string.avoidDistractions1, R.string.earlyMorning1
                , R.string.useWeekends1, R.string.neverProcrastinate1, R.string.findSupport1, R.string.beFutureOne1, R.string.checkProgress1,
                R.string.motivateYourself1},{R.string.treatPeopleWell1, R.string.neverWasteTimeToChangethingsYouCannotChange1,
                R.string.expectSomethingBeautiful1, R.string.assumeTheBestOnPeople1, R.string.focusOnTasks1,
                R.string.avoidDepressingPeople1, R.string.eatClean1, R.string.avoidTVNews1,
                R.string.theBestisnotCome1, R.string.findThingsTobeGrateful1}, {R.string.focusOnEarning1, R.string.stopExchangingTimeAgainstMoney1, R.string.dontPursueSomeoneDream1
                , R.string.stepOutYourComfortZone1, R.string.haveGoalsForAlllife1, R.string.findMindedPeople1, R.string.saveFirst1,
                R.string.putYourMoneyToWork1, R.string.neverBuyThingsYouCannotAfford1, R.string.believeThatYouWillBeRich1},
                {R.string.spenLessTimeWithNegativePeople1, R.string.avoidPeopleWhoCannotControlStress1,
                        R.string.findQuietPlaces1, R.string.workingManyProjectsIncreasesStress1, R.string.stopWatchingNewsOnTV1,
                        R.string.acceptProjectsThatYouEnjoy1, R.string.noMultitasking1, R.string.noScreenTime1, R.string.meditation1
                        , R.string.physicalActivities1},{R.string.visionary1, R.string.strategicActing1, R.string.goalDriven1,
                R.string.selfManagement1, R.string.teamBuilding1, R.string.communication1, R.string.accountability1,
                R.string.prblemSolver1, R.string.creativity1, R.string.agility1}};

          for (int j =0;j<buttonsName.length;j++) {
              for (int k = 0;k<titles.length; k++){
                  holder.mTitle.setText(titles[j][k]);

          }
          }
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context,Details.class);
                i.putExtra("Title" ,dataList.get(position).getTitle());
                i.putExtra("Content",dataList.get(position).getContent());
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return row;
    }




 class ViewHolder{
       TextView mTitle;
        TextView mContent;
        Data myData;
 }


}
```